# Github not sending Webhook for inactive deployment

Tags: github, github-webhook

Why is github not sending a Webhook for the state change to "inactive" of a deployment? How can I know in my app when a deployment changed to inactive?

Github Docs: The new state. Can be pending, success, failure, or error.
https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#deployment_status